# We need some help on how to utilize the Apple ID on multiple Apple computers in a network

Tags: network, apple-id

We have 8 Apple Computers on a network in a dental office where users move from machine to machine and have no need to use any Apple ID capabilities. Each machine has several users in addition to the administrator. We set up each machine without an Apple ID but are constantly reminded to set an Apple ID.

Is there any way to stop the reminders or alternatively set up one ID for use on all the machines on all user accounts that the administrator would essentially control? We would find one Apple ID useful, but we don't want to do anything that might upset the network.

Answer (score 1):

We have a few Macs at work among the multitude of PCs and all I did was create one AppleID using a company email address that comes to the IT department and then log into all of the Macs with that ID.

That way when you have updates and the like you have one common AppleID that only you know the password to and the Macs stop bugging you.